# Adding an object viewer to a Unity Editor Window

Tags: c#, unity

I'm wondering if its possible to add an object viewer (For example when you import an .fbx file into unity you can see a small preview of it in the inspector) to a Unity Editor Window? I've looked through the docs and didn't seem to be able to find anything for this

Thanks,

Lewis

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly what you're looking for, but the way I've solved this in the past is to dynamically create a camera in the editor and have it do a render to texture that I display in the editor window itself using something like [GUILayout.Box](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUILayout.Box.html) with the RenderTexture in it.